# Use JQuery to Change SRC on Selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to change part of the src of an img tag based on what option is selected from the drop down. Here's where I'm at. I'm trying to charge NED to ALG or ARG depending on what is chosen.

**page.php**

```
<div>
  <img src="http://img.fifa.com/images/flags/4/ned.png" class="tinyimg">
</div>
<div>
  <select class="usernation form-control input-lg">
    <option disabled selected>Choose a Team</option>
    <option value="alg">Algeria</option>
    <option value="arg">Argentina</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**header.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".usernation").change(function(){
  // Code to Change
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".usernation").change(function() {
    $(".tinyimg").attr("src", "http://img.fifa.com/images/flags/4/" + $(this).val() + ".png");
});
```